# Switch to different component after button click with React

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick, components

I am absolutely new to React and need to create a button to take the user from a current component (`MovieView`) to the main one (`MainView)`. I managed to create it properly and I used `onClick` to trigger the display of `MainView`. I know I cannot call a class from a function (so as console says), so I created a second function to be called and trigger `MainView`. But as you may wonder, it does not work. This is the code I am using:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MainView } from '../main-view/main-view';

function NewButton() {
  return <MainView />;
}

export class MovieView extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { movie } = this.props;

    if (!movie) return null;

    return (
      <div className="movie-view">
        <img className="movie-poster" src={movie.imagePath} />
        <div className="movie-title">
          <span className="label">Title: </span>
          <span className="value">{movie.title}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="movie-description">
          <span className="label">Description: </span>
          <span className="value">{movie.plot}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="movie-genre">
          <span className="label">Genre: </span>
          <span className="value">{movie.genre.name}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="movie-director">
          <span className="label">Director: </span>
          <span className="value">{movie.director.name}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="back-movies">
          <button onClick={NewButton}>Back</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Could you any seeing this to point the path to take or how I can call this `MainView` class properly. I understand it's a simple task, but I am afraid I still haven't absorbed React principles yet. Thanks in advance to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without introducing additional dependencies, probably the easiest way for this example is to use state to track if the button has been clicked. If it has been clicked, render `MovieView`, if not render `MainView`.

For this you need to following:

- Set state variable that tracks that `MainView` should be rendered in `onClick` event. (boolean will probably suffice)
- in `render()`:

  - if the state var is false, render the content of `MovieView`.
  - if the state var is true, render the `MainView` component.

Implementation details are left as an exercise :)

If you're using a router already (like `react-router`) you could probably just update the url to an url that is linked to the `MainView` component..

Comment: Nic, thanks a lot, but although I managed to set `showMainView` as `false` (with the help of Hannibal B. Moulvad, I don't know how to make the switch on/off for `render()`.  I manage to display `MainView`, but only as additional to `MovieView`. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: @cgobbet Would it work if you added an if statement in `render()` based on `showMainView`? I.e.: `if (showMainView) { return <MainView/> } else { return /* other-stuff */ }`

Comment: thanks a million. I will do that from scratch with your hints tomorrow, when I come back to life.

Answer (score 0):

I make the Class into a Function Component instead, and implement it like this :-)

```
import React from "react";
import { MainView } from '../main-view/main-view';

export const MovieView = ({ movie }) => {
    const { showMainView, setShowMainView } = React.useState(false);

    if (!!movie) {
        return null;
    }

    function toggleMainView() {
        setShowMainView(true);
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            { showMainView ? (
                <MainView />
            ) : (
                <div className="movie-view">
                    <img className="movie-poster" src={movie.imagePath} />
                    <div className="movie-title">
                        <span className="label">Title: </span>
                        <span className="value">{movie.title}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="movie-description">
                        <span className="label">Description: </span>
                        <span className="value">{movie.plot}</span>
                    </div>

                    <div className="movie-genre">
                        <span className="label">Genre: </span>
                        <span className="value">{movie.genre.name}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="movie-director">
                        <span className="label">Director: </span>
                        <span className="value">{movie.director.name}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="back-movies">
                        <button onClick={() => toggleMainView()}>Back</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
export default MovieView;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add or remove components or show a new view based on an user action in react we need to do this via state .

```
import React from 'react';
import { MainView } from '../main-view/main-view';

export class MovieView extends React.Component {

constructor() {
super();

this.state = {
  showMainView: false;
};
}

toggleMainView = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ showMainView: 
!prevState.showMainView})) 

render() {
const { movie } = this.props;
const { showMainView } = this.state;
if (!movie) return null;

return (
  <div className="movie-view">
    <img className="movie-poster" src={movie.imagePath} />
    <div className="movie-title">
      <span className="label">Title: </span>
      <span className="value">{movie.title}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="movie-description">
      <span className="label">Description: </span>
      <span className="value">{movie.plot}</span>
    </div>

    <div className="movie-genre">
      <span className="label">Genre: </span>
      <span className="value">{movie.genre.name}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="movie-director">
      <span className="label">Director: </span>
      <span className="value">{movie.director.name}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="back-movies">
      <button onClick={this.toggleMainView}>Back</button>
    </div>
    // render the mainView based on the state
    { showMainView && <MainView />}
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reached a solution that I'd not do with the help I had here. I have first pasted here some pieces of code but, I believe it can be helpful to give the whole answer.

So, the question I placed here was regarding a component called `<MovieView`, that was a part of an app that interacted with another component (in another file) called `MainView`.

The solution was the insertion of the method `onClick` on the live 14 of `<MovieView>` and the button on line 39 that you can see [at this file on Github](https://github.com/cgobbet/react-client). If the file was updated, check the version for November 22nd.

The solution had, however, been found in the main component, `<MainView>`, adding code on lines 48 and 49. Here is the link to the file: https://github.com/cgobbet/react-client/blob/master/src/components/main-view/main-view.jsx

The repository with the whole app is on this page: https://github.com/cgobbet/react-client.

And sorry for the reviewers (I had accidentally deleted part of the fantastic answer submitted by @nick-miller.